# Touch times to authenticate user

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition

for a project I gathered touch data of different users when they tap a rhythm repeatedly on the touch screen in a game.

```
[
0.23076923076923,
0.46153846153846,
0.69230769230769,
0.92307692307692,
1.1538461538462,
1.8461538461538,
2.3076923076923,
2.7692307692308,
3.2307692307692,
3.6923076923077,
4.3846153846154,
4.6153846153846,
4.8461538461538,
5.0769230769231,
5.3076923076923
]
```

This is one such dataset. It is an simple array of points in time in seconds the user has touched the screen since the start of the game.
I have a lot of "training" data where the user has tried to learn his pattern (like the dataset above).
Now I want to teach a algorithm with the training data that the user normally touches. 
Later on I want to give the algorithm a single data set and it gives me a probability how likely it is that this is the user that learned the pattern or not.

I only vaguely now that this is part of machine learning and pattern recognition but i could not find a fitting algorithm that provides a solution to my problem. Maybe the main problem is that the examples are only like "how likely is a sunny day tomorrow" or only pure mathematical equations that are hard to break down to a actual problem without advanced knowledge of this particular problem

**Do you have any tips on what algorithm I should look for or what a similar problem like this is called?**

With no knowledge in this field it is hard to find the correct problem that describes the one I have.

Comment: Your english is very good, actually ;) The problem with this question is how broad it is. Also, you may be interested in [stats.SE], our sister site for statistics.

Comment: Ok i'll ask it there. Is there a way to transfer my question or do i have to copy/paste it?

Comment: Please flag it for the mods. They will migrate your question to stats.SE.